# Cannot load Google Map Url in Android WebView

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I try to load the Google Map Url in a WebView with the following code:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com";

WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

//webview settings
webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

and it cannot be loaded (blank).
But the other urls (e.g. http://www.google.com) can be loaded without any problem.

Please help !

Comment: Did you add the following permission to the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`? the app needs permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. The WebView must use a custom WebChromeClient which implements WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(). This method is called by the WebView to obtain permission to disclose the user's location to JavaScript.